# PHP Script to 'filter out' a specific part of the DOM tree

Tags: php, dom

I'm looking for a php script that can go through the HTML output of a PHP function and filter out one piece of it, and return the relevant bit.

So I use a php function, and it outputs code like this:

```
<ul>
<li>blabla</li>
<li>blabla</li>
<li>
   <ul>
     <li>This is interesting!</li>
     <li>This too!</li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I just want the nested UL, and not the parent UL. So just this:

```
<ul>
   <li>This is interesting!</li>
   <li>This too!</li>
</ul>
```

As I'm still learning my way around PHP, I have no idea how to go about this...Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple dom for this: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Simple dom allows you to assign a callback for each element in the html, here's an example:

```
function my_callback($element)
{
    if ($element->tag=='b')
    {
        $element->outertext = str_replace("apples","oranges",$element->innertext);
    }
}
```

and you can work with it like so:

```
$html = str_get_html('<html> your data </html>');
$html->set_callback('my_callback');

echo $html; //Modifed
```

The html is only modifed when dumping the data, if you need to do specific modifications your best of doing them manually like so:

```
$elements = $html->find('ul li ul');
```

if you wanted to modify the li in some way you can then do:

```
foreach($elements as $item) 
{
    $item->class = "some_class";
}
```

Comment: Works brilliantly! Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) class and its related classes. You should probably also use [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/domxpath) to do the searching. Your code might look something like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($str); // where $str is the HTML string

$x = new DOMXPath($dom);

$childuls = $x->query('//ul/li/ul'); // find ul elements with parent ul and li
echo $dom->saveXML($childuls->item(0)); // output the XML for this element only
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll keep advocating this library cus its just awesome :) http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/